# How can I change my twitter handle on my profile?

Tags: support, stack-exchange, user-accounts, twitter

I changed my twitter handle recently. How can I change this on my Stack Exchange profile?

Comment: Just.. edit your profile? Am I missing something and are we talking about the network-wide profile page perhaps?

Comment: If so, your [network profile](http://stackexchange.com/users/1118419/christopher-chipps) looks up to date.

Comment: Also, the network profile doesn't (yet) reflect the recent profile updates, so the dedicated Twitter ID field is not yet supported. Presumably this has to wait for *all* SE sites to support the field first.

Comment: Yes, the network profile. I hardly ever change anything and the interface looks different since I've attempted to change it. My twitter handle is no longer what is states it is on my profile.

Comment: The link I can see on your network profile is also being used on just about every other SE account you have here. The network profile is automatically updated from your oldest SE account.

Comment: As such you just need to edit your SE accounts, the twitter link I see on the network profile is just part of your *About Me* section.

Comment: Many thanks @MartijnPieters!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your network profile is updated from your oldest Stack Exchange account, so you'll have to edit that account to see the changes reflected. It can take a while to copy the changes across.

The Twitter URL in your network profile is part of your *About Me* section; the newer Twitter ID field added to user profiles is not yet supported by the network profile; presumably that will be rectified once all Stack Exchange sites support the new profile options.

Comment: I removed my wesite URL from my oldest profile on SO some time ago (several weeks?) but it is still showing on my network profile (even after syncing also some time ago)

Comment: @DavidPostill: I see you did the right thing and [posted a new question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/258070/website-url-not-updating-in-network-profile). :-)