# Website URL not updating in network profile

Tags: support

I removed my website URL from my oldest profile on SO (and my profile on SU) some time ago (several weeks?) but it is still showing on my network profile (even after syncing also some time ago, and again yesterday).

`Sync with oldest profile (Programmers). Last sync 13h ago.`

Is this a bug (with the new profile code)?

Network profile:

[image]

SO profile:

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As the message you cite specifically says, your oldest profile is that on Programmers.SE, not that on SO. To remove the URL, you'll need to remove it on Programmers.

Comment: Well spotted :/. Is there a badge for stupidity? Or for alzheimers? I have no memory of signing up to programmers first. Both programmers and SO are 1 year and 1 month ... ;)

Comment: Mouse over that "1 year and 1 month" and you should get an exact data/time. (You signed up on Programmers about 5 days before Stack Overflow.)

Comment: So I did. Alzheimers it is :/